# unable to login as admin once I deploy a custom user store bundle and copy user store xml on startup - wos2 identity server 5.11

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have developed a custom userstore that extends UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager to handle customer login (domain customer), but when I deploy this bundle, admin login is not working anymore, I don't know why it's triggering the custom user store database connection, in logs I can see it's calling a function doGetUserNameFromUserIDWithID in class UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager. Hence I got an SQL error since I'm using wrong DB password (check following logs).
The question is why without my bundle the admin can log normally to console, when I deploy the bundle JAR along with user store xml (e.g. customer.xml) the admin is trying to use this secondary store to authenticate instead of primary store?

Please support,  thank you,

PFB config details

wso2is 5.11 console url: https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp

Custom userstore Java class:

```
org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore
public class SecondaryCustomUserStore extends UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager{...}
```

snippet of userstore xml: /repository/deployment/server/userstores/customer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore">
      <Property name="url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@//test.com</Property>
      <Property name="userName">test1</Property>
      <Property encrypted="true" name="password">wrong_password</Property>
      <Property name="driverName">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</Property>
```

Deployment.toml snippet:

```
[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true
[user_store]
type = "read_write_ldap_unique_id"
connection_url = "ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}"
connection_name = "uid=admin,ou=system"
connection_password = "admin"
base_dn = "dc=wso2,dc=org" 
[database.identity_db]
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host.docker.internal)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orclpdb2)))"
username = "user"
password = "Id@333333"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
[user_store_mgt]
allowed_user_stores=["org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager", "org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager","org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager","org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager","org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore"]
```

Error logs:

wso2is511_1  | [2022-10-18 17:46:44,984] [8e36165e-ad29-4520-890f-9624450ce205]  INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore} - Second
aryCustomUserStore doGetUserNameFromUserIDWithID...userID=56c92c55-519e-4e53-af03-916c41005e24
wso2is511_1  | [2022-10-18 17:46:50,842] [8e36165e-ad29-4520-890f-9624450ce205] ERROR {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool} - Unable to create initi
al connections of pool. java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
wso2is511_1  |
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:441)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:436)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1027)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:551)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:500)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1280)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:690)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:782)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
wso2is511_1  |  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:704)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:744)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:676)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:154)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.getDBConnection(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1197)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.doGetUserNameFromUserIDWithID(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:1344)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore.doGetUserNameFromUserIDWithID(SecondaryCustomUserStore.java:62)
wso2is511_1  |  at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserStoreInternalWithId(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:7286)

Comment: When adding a custom secondary userstore, you do not need to do any changes in the `deployment.toml` except for the `allowed_user_stores` config. Therefore can you try reverting any configuration that you have done any of the files and start the identity server pack? Also make sure to remove any unnecessary files that you have manually created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able now to login as admin along with deploying my custom userstore, now the custom store is different than primary one. I have changed the extends of custom store class (SecondaryCustomUserStore) from  UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager to JDBCUserStoreManager and used the 5.9 methods implementation. Also updated deployment file.

```
public class SecondaryCustomUserStore extends JDBCUserStoreManager {....}

[super_admin]
admin_role = "admin"
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account= true

[user_store]
type = "read_write_ldap_unique_id"
connection_url = "ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}"
connection_name = "uid=admin,ou=system"
connection_password = "admin"
base_dn = "dc=wso2,dc=org" 
[user_store_mgt]
allowed_user_stores=["org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager","org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager", "org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager","org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager","org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore"]
[database.identity_db]
............
[database.shared_db]
...........
```

Comment: If you were able to fix this by changing the type from `UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager` to `JDBCUserStoreManager`, by best guess is that you have missed to add a config in the userstore configurations saying that the userstore does support unique id capability. If your userstore does not support that there is a good chance that it failed when iterating throught the userstores

Comment: userstore functionality is another matter. Im checking it now , where can I  add this config to the userstore to say that it support unique id? I think wso2is supports backward compatibility (5.11 support 5.9 userstore).  Thank you for ur support . However I will open a new ticket in case I have custom userstore issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood this is expected. Seems like from the deployment.toml you have configured the secondary custom user store as your user store. I don't see any configuration for the another primary user store configuration. In that case in the custom user store xml file if you use the wrong password it will fail the login with the oracle database.

Comment: Dear Buddhima, I have updated Deployment.toml, could yo have a look again, note that I still have same issue, as my understanding primary store under [user_store], it's LDAP RW by default,  and under [user_store_mgt]  I added the class to be available in management console. But he problem is when deploying the bundle (JAR),login as admin is not working anymore. SO how best way to define a secondary store in deployment.toml without affecting primary store?

Comment: @SalimR You just need to define the userstore manager class in `deployment.toml` under `allowed_user_stores` (I see you have done that). You can add the secondary userstore from the carbon console.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is you need to configure this as a secondary userstore. Since this is extending the `UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager` you need to extend several more methods than in `JDBCUserStoreManager`
IS 5.11.0 does support backward compatibility to you should be able to deploy the existing implementation given the dependencies does match with IS 5.11.0.

Comment: yes the bundle 5.9 works in 5.11

Comment: @SalimR You just need to define the userstore manager class in `deployment.toml` under `allowed_user_stores` (I see you have done that). You can add the secondary userstore from the carbon console.